# Java export server : (SVGConverter.java:convert:108) responce : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Highcharts

Tags: java, tomcat, phantomjs, highcharts-ng

System : windows 10 and AWS EC2

I have follow below steps:

1. install jdk
2. install tomcat8
3. install maven
4. PhantomJS
5. Updated app-convert.properties according to system (windows/linux)
6. Added new required highchart java-script files in diectory /phantomjs
7. Updated required java-scripts files names in resources.json
8. Export war/ install export server from repository
9. Deploy war in tomcat/ start server using mvn jetty:run

On preview server logs error

```
[ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-25 05:19:49] (ExportController.java:writeFileToStream:356) Tried to read file from filesystem: File '/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp/export4935023327417038147/output/UOBhqYub.png' does not exist
```

So I debug Server.java, server is responding as

```
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: highcharts".
```

> (SVGConverter.java:convert:108) responce json: ReferenceError: Can't
>   find variable: Highcharts

I have added required js files in resource/phontomjs directory and mentioned these files in resources.json.

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server/issues/20)

Please correct me if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, my stupid mistake, I was using old version of highchart java-scripts files.